# How do you explicitly specify a parameterized type for an existential type in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, wildcard, type-systems, existential-type

In ***Programming in Scala***, the following example is given to show how to reference a Java class with wildcards.  The method `javaSet2ScalaSet` takes a type T.  Typically, you can always explicitly supply a parameterized type.  But in this case where `(new Wild).contents` is existential, a normal type parameter is not acceptable.

The compiler is able to perform some magic and infer an appropriate parameter when `javaSet2ScalaSet` is called without a type parameter.  Viewing what the compiler supplies with scalac –Xprint:typer shows that it assigns a value of ?0 for T.   This can’t be provided manually.

Is this a special case that only works for an inferred type, or is there some way to explicitly supply the type?

```
  // This is a Java class with wildcards
  public class Wild {
    Collection<?> contents() {
      Collection<String> stuff = new Vector<String>();
      stuff.add("a");
      stuff.add("b");
      stuff.add("see");
      return stuff;
    }
  }

  import scala.collection.mutable.Set
  import java.util.Collection

  abstract class SetAndType {
    type Elem
    val set: Set[Elem]
  }

  def javaSet2ScalaSet[T](jset: Collection[T]): SetAndType = {
    val sset = Set.empty[T]  // now T can be named!

    val iter = jset.iterator
    while (iter.hasNext)
      sset += iter.next()

    return new SetAndType {
      type Elem = T
      val set = sset
    }
  }

val setAndType = javaSet2ScalaSet((new Wild).contents)
```

Comment: You can write `javaSet2ScalaSet[T forSome {type T}]` (which is the same as `javaSet2ScalaSet[_]`). Is that what you mean?

Comment: You can't write `javaSet2ScalaSet[T forSome {type T}]`.  The compiler complains with unbound wildcard type.  Same with `javaSet2ScalaSet[_])`.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a syntactic limitation, not an inherent one. Here's how you can declare it:

```
def javaSet2ScalaSet[C <: Collection[T] forSome { type T }](jset: C): SetAndType = {
  val sset = Set.empty[T forSome { type T }]

  val iter = jset.iterator
  while (iter.hasNext)
    sset += iter.next()

  return new SetAndType {
    type Elem = T forSome { type T }
    val set = sset
  }
}
```

Comment: `T forSome { type T }` is just `Any`

Comment: No, it is not.  For one thing, if you have two variables declared `Set[T forSome { Type T }]` you couldn't assign one to the other, whereas you could do so if you had two `Set[Any]`.

Comment: Yes, it **is** :) https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/248tqVplRXCmXBjn647Edg/5 You're confusing with `Set[T] forSome { type T }`. `Set[T] forSome { type T }` is not `Set[Any]` but `T forSome { type T }` is `Any`, so `Set[T forSome { type T }]` is `Set[Any]`.

Comment: According to the spec ([see](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#simplification-rules) "Simplification rules" 4 in 3.2.12): *"An existential type `T forSome { Q }` where `Q` contains a clause type `t[tps] >:L <: U` is equivalent to the type `T′ forSome { Q }` where `T′` results from `T` by replacing every covariant occurrence of `t` in `T` by `U` and by replacing every contravariant occurrence of `t` in `T` by `L`."*

Comment: The occurrence of `T` in `T forSome { type T }` is covariant so can be replaced with `Any` although its occurrence in `Set[T] forSome { type T }` is invariant.

Answer (score 0):

(Q1) >> Is this a special case that only works for an inferred type. <<

The compiler does not infer the type of your Java collection to be of type Collection. It only knows that it is a collection with elements of *some* type.

(Q2) >> or is there some way to explicitly supply the type? <<

No. An existential type is not to be supplied. It is not a free variable to be bound (since it is bound already).

Look at it this way: suppose you were able to provide the type. You would then expect the compiler to check that the provided type matches the type of elements in your Java collection. But there is no way for the compiler to determine that. So in case they wouldn't match, you would anyhow only find out at runtime.

If you would like to tell the Scala-compiler that you know that the elements in the java collection are of type String (e.g. you want to call x.length) then you could cast the elements with asInstanceOf[String]. But that will not introduce type-safety. You will again only find out at run-time if it would be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I realize the specific type is not to be supplied, but the original question remains.  In `javaSet2ScalaSet[???]((new Wild).contents)`, is there some formulation of an existential type for ??? that is legal?  If not, this expression only works if the compiler implicitly provides the value of T.  To me, it would be strange if only an implicit value is allowed.

Comment: I guess this doesn’t bother anybody, but I do see it as an anomaly.  Essentially, in a call to `javaSet2ScalaSet`, there is no way you can specify T such that the type of the formal parameter `jset` will be `Collection[T] forSome {type T}` because `jset` is of type `Collection[T]`.

Comment: The weakest type parameter that you can give to javaSet2ScalaSet is "something that is unknown". However, the collection that you provide has elements of type "something *else* that is unknown". They can never match.

Comment: Yes, it does appear that this is one of those corner cases in which you must rely upon the compiler to perform its magic.